# How I can write Database query that shows two words in one stroke?

Tags: mysql

I have a database

- books

  - id
  - title
  - summary
  - year
- genres

  - id
  - name
- author

  - id
  - name
- books_genres

  - id_book
  - id_genre
- books_author

  - id_book
  - id_author

i need request that can present 2 or more genres or author in one stroke

Title: lol
Summary: lorem
Genres: Novell, BDSM
Authors: Uncle John, Aunt Dad.

i wrote something like this, but it show two dublicated strokes with different genres

```sql
SELECT 
    books.title, genres.name 
FROM 
    books, books_genres, genres 
WHERE books.id = books_genres.id_book AND genres.id = books_genres.id_genre
```

Comment: You can use [INNER JOIN](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx) to join the tables.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson again shows 2 dublicated strokes  with 2 different genres

Comment: You can use DISTINCT in your query with books to prevent duplication

Comment: @MagnusEriksson maybe it's problem with my php code?

```php
 echo "Title: ".$data['title']."<br>";
                    echo "Summary: ".$data['summary']."<br>";
                    echo $data['name'];
```

Comment: It's group_concat() you need if you want to combine field values from multiple rows. See the duplicate topic on how to use it.